# R function to separate characters of unequal width

Tags: r, string, character

I am trying to separate a column with time increments that are in a character format.

The format is MM:SS for most observations, but there are a few with the HH:MM:SS format. I am trying to separate into columns based on the ":" so I can reduce the times to seconds to preform some basic analysis.

I would like to get this:

```
     Time
    1   11:15
    2   12:36
    3 1:15:17
```

into this:

```
        Hour  Minuet Second 
    1    NA     11   15
    2    NA     12   36
    3     1     15   17
```

I have tried

```
      separate(df, time, into = c("Hours", "Minuets", "Seconds"), by = ":")
```

Which returns:

```
         Hour  Minuet Second 
    1    11     15   NA
    2    12     36   NA
    3     1     15   17
```

Comment: I think `by = ":"` ought to be an argument to `separate`, not an element of the `into` vector.

Comment: that was an error on my end. I have edited the code above for clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  separate(time, c("Hour", "Minute", "Second"), sep = ":", fill = "left")
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------

#   Hour Minute Second
# 1 <NA>     11     15
# 2 <NA>     12     36
# 3    1     15     17
```

## Data

```r
#dput(df)
df <- structure(list(time = c("11:15", "12:36", "1:15:17")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

`?separate`

> fill If sep is a character vector, this controls what happens when there are not enough pieces. 
>   There are three valid options:

```
>"warn" (the default): emit a warning and fill from the right

>"right": fill with missing values on the right

>"left": fill with missing values on the left
```